# Normal RHEL and PREEMPT_RT patches on same system ? is it possible

Tags: linux, rhel, preempt-rt

Im new to PREEMPT_RT patches, so i was wondering if i can install RHEL and PREEMPT_RT patches in same system, like if one of the core can run PREEMPT_RT s and other run RHEL

so i can do complex time critical tasks on PREEMPT_RT and give a GUI on RHEL which would display it?

is there any such method?

Comment: Stock kernel lets you dedicate cores to specific tasks and interrupts. That generally gives better throughput than preempt.

Comment: @stark How exactly?(CGroups,CPU affinity?)

Answer (score 0):

Use isolcpus on the cmdline to prevent scheduling other processes and taskset to set cpu affinity for the critical processes. For example, on a 4-core system, you might reserve cpus 1-3 for the critical process and schedule everything else on cpu 0.  When the critical process is the only task running, preempt is not needed.